# Is the formula of a Dyson orbital independent of whether there is degeneracy or not in the HOMO of the neutral?

Tags: symmetry, hartree-fock, orbitals

A Dyson orbital is defined as:
$$
\textrm{Dy}(x) = \int dx_1 \ldots dx_{N-1} \, (\Psi^+(x_1,\ldots,x_{N-1}))^* \, \Psi^0(x_1,\ldots,x_{N-1}, x),\tag{1}
$$
where $\Psi^0$ and $\Psi^+$ are the total wavefunctions of the neutral and cation, respectively.
For $N$-electron molecule within Hartree-Fock picture, it's known that in most cases the Dyson orbital is similar to the HOMO of the neutral species and this is due to the fact that the MO's of the cation often look similar to the first $N-1$ MO's of the neutral. Let's take an example of the $\ce{CO_2}$ molecular orbital obtained by Hartree-Fock method where the HOMO has $\pi$ symmetry and is thus doubly degenerate. One may identify these HOMO as $p_x$ and $p_y$. Now the HOMO of $\ce{CO_2^+}$ obtained with the same method also has $\pi$ symmetry but is not degenerate, and I guess depending on the initial guess, it may collapse to having either $p_x$ or $p_y$. If say, it has $p_y$ symmetry and then you calculate the Dyson orbital, it will have $p_x$ symmetry.

What looks strange to me is that the Dyson orbital does not seem to respect the degeneracy of the neutral. **Or is it that there is a special treatment for degeneracy in calculating Dyson orbital?**

Comment: IMHO this is a problem of Hartree-Fock, not a problem of the Dyson orbitals. If you use FCI wavefunctions in the calculation of Dyson orbitals, you should get perfectly degenerate HOMOs

Comment: @wzkchem5 do you mean when I use FCI to get the neutral and cation wavefunctions, I will get $n$ different Dyson orbitals where $n$ is the degree of degeneracy? But how can I have more than one different Dyson orbitals when there is only one formula to get it?

Comment: In this case you have an infinite number of possible choices of $\Psi^+$, therefore the Dyson orbital is indeed non-unique, up to unitary rotations in an $n$-dimensional space

Comment: Isn't that true already in HF because there is an infinite possible pair of neutral's degenerate HOMO? You can rotate the HOMO manifold without affecting ground state energy.

Comment: You're right. What I said only explains that Dyson orbitals from FCI respect spatial symmetry, while those from HF don't, and degeneracy is a different thing from symmetry. But then, how do you define the degeneracy of Dyson orbitals, when there is only one Dyson orbital for a given molecule? Or are you instead referring to the non-degeneracy of the Dyson orbital of the neutral molecule with that of the cation?

Comment: I see your point. by design HF indeed doesn't handle the degeneracy of ground states. However, for the case of $CO_2^+$ within HF in the original post, I am thinking of 'artificially' generating the other degenerate wavefunction by manually rotating all if its MO's by 90 degree. It should have the same GS energy . I have not checked but it looks like the two wavefunctions are also orthogonal. This way, I will have two Dyson orbitals, each associated with the $CO_2^+$ HF wavefunction within the two-fold artificial degenerate subspace.

Comment: I wonder why you asked [this](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/161607/27342) on Chem.SE instead of here?

Comment: Well because I find the topic of the question fits that stack group. It does not mean it won't fit in the other groups, but as I see it Chem.SE is the best fit.

Comment: @nougako You haven't got an answer there, why not ask it here? 100% of your questions on MMSE in July got answers and I suspect that one might get and answer here. This Dyson orbitals question might be harder though. Make sure you use the "from-chem-se" tag and provide a link to the original question.